# How can I remove the excess information at the beginning of each line in OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

At the beginning of every line in my OSX terminal are the words

`Sephs-MacBook-Pro:current_dir seph$`

I'd like to trim it up somehow, perhaps to `current_dir seph$` or even `current_dir$`.  As far as my purposes go, everything but the current directory is assumable (only user, only laptop).

*How can I remove some of this excess information at the beginning of each line in OSX's terminal?*

Comment: This is controlled by the `PS1` bash variable and is set in one the set-up files, typically `~/.bashrc`. Look for `PS1` in `man bash` and you will see all the values that can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I want to shorten the prompt, I use the command `PS1=\$\` (there's a trailing space there).

Obviously you can make this a permanent change in `~/.bashrc` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Find `export PS1` line in your `~/.bashrc` and replace it with:

`export PS1="\W \u\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"`

This will show the output as follows: `directory_basename user$`

For example if you were in the directory `/etc/` and your username is `seth`:

`etc seth$` will be the output.

You can build your own PS1 variable for .bashrc [here](http://bashrcgenerator.com/).